# Система событий в react?

Tags: reactjs, redux

Через что можно вызвать метод в компоненте который находиться неизвестно где?
Например есть карта города и есть поле поиска по районам в этой карте. Но это поле находится во всплывающем верхнем меню, которое появляется после скролла вниз, а карта во 2й колонке внизу страницы. И оба компонента друг о друге не знают. 
Но при поиске района в верхнем меню мы должны переместиться на выбранный район города. То есть компонент выпадаюший список должен вызвать метод компонента карты города, выделить конкретный район по его ID. 
Для таких целей что лучше использовать?

Comment: не специалист по react, но я связь между компонентами делал через состояние. Меняешь состояние одним компоненом (через редьюсер ессно), другой заинтересованный компонент (которое получает то же состояние) обновляет свои пропсы с новыми данными и может или перерисовать себя или выполнить какую то логику

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этих целей используются технологии, использующие общее хранилище:

**flux:**

> Flux — это архитектура, которую команда Facebook использует при работе
>   с React. Это не фреймворк, или библиотека, это новый архитектурный
>   подход, который дополняет React и принцип однонаправленного потока
>   данных. https://github.com/facebook/flux

**redux:**

> Redux - это библиотека JavaScript с открытым исходным кодом для
>   управления состоянием приложения. Он чаще всего используется с такими
>   библиотеками, как React или Angular для создания пользовательских
>   интерфейсов.
>   https://redux.js.org/

**mobx:**

> MobX это простое, опробованное в бою решение для управления состоянием
>   вашего приложения. MobX это автономная библиотека, но большинство
>   используют ее в связке с React. https://mobx.js.org/

ну и многие другие